# How to join object values into a string? join() for objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've an object content and I'd like to output it as string. With `<br/>` at the end of the line.

Now if it was array, I would do: `join("<br/>")`

But how to do same with objects?

I could go around the problem, but changing object into an array doing `$.each` and `push`, but that's unnecessary code isn't it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the object in question?

Comment: Can't you just write a `for (property in object)` loop and concatenate the values onto a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built in functions to do this. To avoid `each` you can use `stringify` and then format the string

```
JSON.htmlify = function(obj){
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
}
```

You can also replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`, or perform any other formating.